# Show my data from SSMS SQL into Visual Studio 2012 Datagrid View?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

So I have this code in my form but when I try to click the search button to search for a name and show it into my datagrid view using the details from my sql database, it brings nothing. Just blank datagrid.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim tblClientDetails As New DataTable


    If CON.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        CON.Open()
    End If

    With cmd
        .Connection = CON
        .CommandText = "select * from tblClientDetails where name = @name"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)
        dr = .ExecuteReader

    End With

    While (dr.Read)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = tblClientDetails


    End While
```

My data in sql which i want to be shown in my datagrid below after searching from a textbox
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J9lh.png

My form's data grid looks like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxmF5.png

Comment: Where are you binding your reader to your data table? You are binding a data table to your grid view which is actually blank

Comment: @Amnesh Goel How can I put data into it? I just found this on a tutorial and i'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()    
    If CON.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        CON.Open()
    End If

    sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from tblClientDetails where name = @name"
    sqlCmd.Connection = CON

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim tblClientDetails As New DataTable()
    tblClientDetails.Load(dr)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataTable
    DataGridView1.DataBind()
    CON.Close()            
End Sub
```

Sample example to load a `data reader` to your `data table` and then `data table to your grid` is shown below.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
            Dim MyCommand As SqlCommand
            Dim MyDataTable As DataTable
            Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader
            Dim CityParam As SqlParameter

            MyConnection = New SqlConnection()
            MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DSN_Northwind").ConnectionString

            MyCommand = New SqlCommand()
            MyCommand.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CITY = @CITY "
            MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection

            CityParam = New SqlParameter()
            CityParam.ParameterName = "@CITY"
            CityParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
            CityParam.Size = 15
            CityParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            CityParam.Value = "London"

            MyCommand.Parameters.Add(CityParam)

            MyCommand.Connection.Open()
            MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            MyDataTable = New DataTable()

            MyDataTable.Load(MyReader)

            gvCustomers.DataSource = MyDataTable
            gvCustomers.DataBind()

            MyDataTable.Dispose()
            MyCommand.Dispose()
            MyConnection.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub
```

[Source available here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0360__ADO.net-Database/HowtoloadaDataTablefromaDataReaderVB.htm)

Comment: I get an error in this;
tblClientDetails.Load(dr)
Value cannot be null.

Comment: @Sync try again.. I mistakenly wrote `tblClientDetails.Load(dr)` before opening connection, and I assume u copied that.. remove that line ..

Comment: is there other ways to call my data in sql in my datagrid other than that way?

Comment: I'll look into it and examine it and try to implement it in my form. Thanks a ton!